# For how long do the recv() functions buffer in UDP?

Tags: c, udp

My program contains a thread that waits for UDP messages and when a message is received it runs some functions before it goes back to listening. I am worried about missing a message, so my question is something along the line of, how long is it possible to read a message after it has been sent? For example, if the message was sent when the thread was running the functions, could it still be possible to read it if the functions are short enough? I am looking for guidelines here, but an answer in microseconds would also be appreciated.

Comment: The question should be something like "how long does data stay queued for a UDP stream?", I think. My guess is that as long as the associated file descriptor hasn't been closed data is being queued up by the Kernel up to the buffer-size limit.

Comment: If you're "worried about missing a message", then you shouldn't be using UDP, since UDP doesn't make any guarantees about packet delivery. If you need guaranteed delivery of your data, then consider using TCP instead.

Comment: Even when you know that packet delivery isn't guaranteed, you'd still like to minimize the likelihood of packet loss, since your program will presumably work better if gets a larger percentage of the packets it was intended to get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your computer receives a UDP packet (and there is at least one program listening on the UDP port specified in that packet), the TCP stack will add that packet's data into a fixed-size buffer that is associated with that socket and kept in the kernel's memory space.  The packet's data will stay in that buffer until your program calls recv() to retrieve it.

The gotcha is that if your computer receives the UDP packet and there isn't enough free space left inside the buffer to fit the new UDP packet's data, the computer will simply throw the UDP packet away -- it's allowed to do that, since UDP doesn't make any guarantees that a packet will arrive.

So the amount of time your program has to call recv() before packets start getting thrown away will depend on the size of the socket's in-kernel packet buffer, the size of the packets, and the rate at which the packets are being received.

Note that you can ask the kernel to make its receive-buffer size larger by calling something like this:

```
size_t bufSize = 64*1024;   // Dear kernel:  I'd like the buffer to be 64kB please!
setsockopt(mySock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &bufSize, sizeof(bufSize));
```

… and that might help you avoid dropped packets.  If that's not sufficient, you'll need to either make sure your program goes back to recv() quickly, or possibly do your network I/O in a separate thread that doesn't get held off by processing.

Comment: Best practice would be to make `iSize` typed as `size_t`. Your size won't be negative. You don't need a signed type ;-)

Comment: From the man page, "Most socket-level options utilize an int parameter for option_value." In practice, size_t will have a platform-dependant size which could be equal to an int on 32-bit platform, or double that on 64-bit platforms. Additionally, if setsockopt treats bufSize as an int, asking for too large a buffer could then be read as a negative number (though it's unlikely you'd ask for that large a buffer)... Either way, I would stick with an int.

Comment: @ChrisMcGrath In the 3.6.11 Linux Kernel code, for `SO_RCVBUF`, `optval` is cast to `u32` and is checked against `sysctl_rmem_max` (you can access its value through `sysctl net.core.rmem_max`). The buffer will be expanded to `min((u32)optval, (u32)sysctl_rmem_max).` The size of the buffer won't be greater than the max value of `u32`. No risk of getting a negative size for the buffer. However, being conservative is of course a good point. Note that I am not using the Linux Kernel source code to make a point. I just wanted to share my findings :)

Comment: Interesting, that's good to know. I wonder, if you're on an x64 machine and pass setsockopt a size_t and sizeof(size_t) (8 bytes) is that OK? I suppose casting from any larger type to a smaller type is guaranteed to receive the least significant bits, which would be OK in this case - you'll end up with the value you wanted, as a u32. I guess it still begs the question, why pass in a type which is potentially 8 bytes when you could just make bufSize an unsigned int.